# Alert not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

My alert at the end of my JavaScript doesn't work, and I don't know why. I think that I have concatenated properly, but I don't know why the code doesn't do anything when it reaches the alert.

Here is the code for the HTML:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Play Battleship Free Online!</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Play Battleship!</h1>

    <script src="battleship.js"></script>

    <button onclick="startGame()">Play!</button>

</body>
```

here is the code for CSS (might not be needed):

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    color: black;

}
```

and here is the code for my JavaScript:

```
var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var location1 = randomLoc;
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location2 + 1;

var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;

function startGame() {
    while (isSunk == false){
        guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (Enter a number between 1 and 6): ")
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){
            alert("Please enter a valid number!");
        }else{
            guesses = guesses + 1;
        }

        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
            hits++;
            alert("HIT!");
        } if (hits == 3) {
            isSunk = true;
            alert("You sank my battleship!");
        } else {
            alert("MISS!");
        }
    }

    var stats = "You took " + guesses + "guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);

    alert(stats);

    return;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `hits == hits + 1;` doesn’t do anything. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: thanks, @Xufox, but my console is not showing any errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: @shafteyMalone Look at my suggested edit it will fix an error in your code.

Comment: There is a problem at `else {
                alert("MISS!");
            }`. It does not follow a corresponding if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTFY.

A few things to note:

1. `Math.random` generates a number between 0 and 1, inclusive of 0 but not 1. In your original code you wrote `Math.random() * 5`. This will get a number from 0 to 5, but not inclusive of 5. Flooring this number will get you 0 to 4. So, `location1` could get the value of 0. This may not be desirable.
2. Proper code formatting is important. In the "Hit"/"Miss"/"Sank" chunk of code, the else should be match with the "Hit" block, but due to the formatting, it erroneously matched with the "Sank" block. The formatting makes this hard to be spotted.
3. For boolean variable checking, it is better to just use the variable in your condition without the comparison operator. `while (isSunk == false)` is better  written as `while (!isSunk)`. You don't have to worry about mistyping the double equal sign and it is easier to read. In fact, in your code, you do not even need a flag. `while (hits < 3)` works equally well.
4. Declare global variables sparingly. In your example, it is better to put the variables into the `startGame` method. This localize your variable to where they are used, while also have the added benefit of able to "restart the game" when you click the Play! button for the second time.

```js
function startGame() {
    // Randomly generate a number between 0 to 3, and 
    // add 1, 2, 3 to it to get 1 to 6.
    var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var location1 = randomLoc + 1;
    var location2 = location1 + 1;
    var location3 = location2 + 1;

    var guess;
    var hits = 0;
    var guesses = 0;
    var isSunk = false;

    while (!isSunk){
        guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (Enter a number between 1 and 6): ")
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){
            alert("Please enter a valid number!");
        } else {
            guesses = guesses + 1;
        }

        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
            hits++;
            alert("HIT!");

            if (hits == 3) {
                isSunk = true;
                alert("You sank my battleship!") 
            }
        } else {
            alert("MISS!");
        }             
    }
    var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);    
    alert(stats);    
    return; //Optional
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
        <title>Play Battleship Free Online!</title>    
    </head>

    <body>    
        <h1>Play Battleship!</h1>    
        <script src="battleship.js"></script>    
        <button onclick="startGame()">Play!</button>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Chan MT! This solved my problem. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors in your JavaScript code, see comments below:

```
var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var location1 = randomLoc;
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location2 + 1;

var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;

function startGame() {
    while (isSunk == false){
        guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (Enter a number between 1 and 6): ")
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 6){
            alert("Please enter a valid number!");
        }else{
            guesses = guesses + 1;
        }

        if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
            hits == hits + 1;
            alert("HIT!");
        } if (hits == 3) {
            isSunk = true;
            alert("You sank my battleship!");

            // Missing a closing curly brace
            else {
                alert("MISS!");
            }
        } // End of while-loop
    } // End of startGame()
```

Outside of startGame():

```
    var stats = "You took " + guesses + "guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);

    alert(stats);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jsub, but now my code is infinitely looping the prompt. Any suggestions to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem in your javascript code, check following :

```js
var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var location1 = randomLoc;
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location2 + 1;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;
function startGame() {
 while (isSunk == false) {
  guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (Enter a number between 1 and 6): ")
  if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
   alert("Please enter a valid number!");
  } else {
   guesses = guesses + 1;
  }

  if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
   hits == hits + 1;
   alert("HIT!");
  }
  if (hits == 3) {
   isSunk = true;
   alert("You sank my battleship!");
  } else {
   alert("MISS!");
  }
 }


 var stats = "You took " + guesses + "guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3 / guesses);
 alert(stats);
 return;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<h1>Play Battleship!</h1>
<button onclick="startGame()">Play!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jagjeet Singh, but this just puts my code into an infinite loop of prompts and misses. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You mentioned your alert not working, so we solved it, you need to explain what you actually want to do